# Decompress gzip column data using Hive QL

Tags: encoding, hive, gzip, hiveql

I have a table(`accounting_info`) in Hive that has one of it's column(`info`) data in gzip (binary) compressed format. Is there any way to extract decompressed data, in string format from the column using Hive QL only.

I can only find a way to get the decoded binary data:

`select base64(a.info) from accounting_info a`

This query gives me the encoded string, but I need the actual decompressed string. Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 4.0-alpha1 release or above then it does have a **deserialize** function which can used to deserialize Gzip

Ref:
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-4.0.0-alpha-1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFDeserialize.java#L38-L44